# SignalR connection inside Vue Single File Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, signalr, vue-component, quasar-framework

I’m trying to make a SignalR component however it seems like it never initiates a connection. I’m rather new to all of this so I’d like to know what I’m doing wrong.

I'm not sure if it's because the connection isn't retained or if there's another way to do this.

```html
<template>
  <div style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: 100%">
    <div class="form-group">
      <form>
        <div>
          <label for="userName">Your Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="Name"
            id="userName"
            v-model="userName"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="userMessage">Message</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="Message"
            id="userMessage"
            v-model="userMessage"
          />
        </div>
        <button
          v-on:click="submitCard"
          type="button"
        >Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul
        v-for="(item, index) in messages"
        v-bind:key="index + 'itemMessage'"
      >
        <li><b>Name: </b>{{item.user}}</li>
        <li><b>Message: </b>{{item.message}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
const signalR = require('@aspnet/signalr')
// import { QScrollArea } from 'Quasar'
export default {
  name: 'SignalRIncommingText',
  data () {
    return {
      userName: '',
      userMessage: '',
      connection: '',
      messages: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    // QScrollArea
  },
  methods: {
    submitCard: function () {
      if (this.userName && this.userMessage) {
        // ---------
        //  Call hub methods from client
        // ---------
        this.connection
          .invoke('SendMessage', this.userName, this.userMessage)
          .catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString())
          })

        this.userName = ''
        this.userMessage = ''
      }
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    // ---------
    // Connect to our hub
    // ---------
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://localhost:44382/chat')
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build()
    this.connection.start().catch(function (err) {
      return console.error(err.toString())
    })
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // ---------
    // Call client methods from hub
    // ---------
    var thisVue = this
    thisVue.connection.on('ReceiveMessage', function (user, message) {
      thisVue.messages.push({ user, message })
    })
  }
}
```

When I send a message I get this:

> Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: After a bit more testing, I’ve figured that I am getting a connection… somewhat, it’s just not finishing negotiating.

> [2019-09-09T06:58:53.685Z] Debug: Starting HubConnection.
>
> [2019-09-09T06:58:53.686Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer
>   format 'Text'.
>
> [2019-09-09T06:58:53.687Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request:
>   http://localhost:44382/chat/negotiate.

Found the issue, it had something to do with Cors and HTTPS. It works now.

Comment: I can't guarantee this is the root cause of your problem, but `data()` is not a recommended place for storing rich (non data-only, with methods) objects.

Comment: To follow on with what I think @acdcjunior is referring to, it doesn't look like you need `this.connection` to be reactive so you do not need to define it within `data()`

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Preface: I know nothing about SignalR</sub>

I think the issue is that nothing here is waiting for the connection to establish. You may need to add some sort of *"ready"* flag and use it to control some of your UI elements.

For example

```js
data: () => ({
  userName: '',
  userMessage: '',
  messages: [],
  ready: false
}),
created () {
  this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://localhost:44382/chat')
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build()

  this.connection.start().then(() => {
    this.ready = true // toggle ready flag here
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err.toString())
  })
}
```

and in your template, something like this

```html
<form>
  <fieldset :disabled="!ready">
    <!-- the rest of your form goes in here -->
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

`<fieldset>` elements are handy for disabling a group of form elements at once.

---

You may note that I have not defined `connection` within the `data()` function. This is because it is not a reactive property.

Comment: It almost seems like the connection isn't starting.

Comment: @MathiasChartier what is your `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` property set to (default is 30s)? Do you see any errors show up in the console?

Comment: @MathiasChartier try setting the log level to `Debug` instead of `Information`

Comment: seems like I'm actually connecting. [2019-09-09T06:34:31.898Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: http://localhost:44382/chat/negotiate.
However, it doesn't appear like if the connection is starting.

Comment: @MathiasChartier have you verified that the service is running at `http://localhost:44382` and is reachable by your browser?

Comment: It is running at that port, I also know that it should be reachable since I tried to use another signalr version and it threw me an error saying it isn't for Core but Framework which means it did try to negotiate. If I change the link, then I get an error saying it can't connect.